# Why am I getting an error message about invalid symbols when I try to place an order on Bybit derivatives?

Tags: python, bybit, python-bybit

I am trying to place an order on Bybit usdt perpetual but I can't succeed.

This is my script.

```
client = HTTP(testnet = False, api_key=user_key, api_secret=secret_key)

print(client.place_order(
    category="Linear",
    symbol="MANAUSDT",
    side="Buy",
    orderType="Limit",
    qty="1",
    price="0.65",
    timeInForce="GTC",
    reduceOnly = False,
    isLeverage=1,
))
```

The error message:

```
**InvalidRequestError :** The requested symbol is invalid. (ErrCode: 10029) (ErrTime: 15:44:30).
Request → POST https://api.bybit.com/v5/order/create: {"category": "Linear", "symbol": "MANAUSD", "side": "Buy", "orderType": "Limit", "qty": "1", "price": "0.65", "timeInForce": "GTC", "reduceOnly": false, "isLeverage": 1}.
```

I tried changing the symbol by MANAUSD, MANA/USDT, MANA/USDT:USD... but nothing..

In the same way, if I change category 'Linear' by 'spot', it works.

Note that I get this error for all instruments, MANA is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem myself, i have figured out that it only occures when i set the isLeverage equals to 1. Every other values doesn't change the the outcome, the order is placed, but the leverage get's ignored. Only at 1 seems to be a Problem, even if i run the example here

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/api-explorer/v5/trade/create-order

The image shows the curl request from the example and beneath the response.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7SG5.png)